# Delphi: EInvalidPointer when trying to access XMLDocument

Tags: xml, delphi, root, delphi-2007, txmldocument

The following code throws an "InvalidPointer" exception everytime I try to access the document's root with `XMLDocument.DocumentElement;`.

```
    begin
      XMLDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil); // nil since we don't need an owner
      AStream := TStream.Create;  // stream for output as string
      XMLDocument.loadFromXML(xml);// load string
      if NOT (XMLDocument.IsEmptyDoc) then
       begin      
        XMLDocument.Active := true; // actually automatically done by 'loadFromXML'

        // get document root
        HeadNode := XMLDocument.DocumentElement;

        // add <id>-element, set ID as text
        idNode := HeadNode.AddChild(XML_ID_PLAIN);
        idNode.Text := id;

        // ...
     end;
    end;
```

The string "xml" passed to `loadFromXML(string)` is valid XML, but the XMLDocument's properties "XML" and "DOMDocument" are always `nil`, even though neither the object itself nor its "IsEmptyDoc" properties are. Delphi Version is still 2007.

Has anyone an idea what causes this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a hunch that the answer will become obvious if you tell us what type the `XMLDocument` variable is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that this won't answer your question why happens what you've described, but tries to offer you the correct way to do, what you want. Use the [`LoadXMLData`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Xml.XMLDoc.LoadXMLData) function instead of creating `TXMLDocument` instance by yourself. Here's a sample code:

```
uses
  XMLIntf, XMLDoc;

const
  XMLString =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
    '<Setup>' +
    '  <FirstNode>First Node Value</FirstNode>' +
    '  <SecondNode>Second Node Value</SecondNode>' +
    '</Setup>';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HeadNode: IXMLNode;
  XMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
begin
  try
    XMLDocument := LoadXMLData(XMLString);
    HeadNode := XMLDocument.DocumentElement;
    if Assigned(HeadNode) then
      ShowMessage(HeadNode.NodeName);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```